Git error on vs code multiple apparent accounts
I have been trying to sync my repository to Git Hub without success. It did at one point, then it just stopped and popped up an error, saying the remote doesn't exist, to which I deleted the GitHub account thinking I might start from zero, still didn't want to sync, and kept asking to publish branch, and if I type the name "main" says it already exists. I uninstalled and reinstalled vs code four times because it kept showing me the same repository history, I tried searching for the git credentials, which I couldn't find on settings. Please if someone knows how I could fix this, I would appreciate it.
I deleted the GitHub account thinking I might start from zero, still didn't want to sync, kept asking to publish the branch, and if I type the name "main" says it already exists. I uninstalled and reinstalled vs code four times because it kept showing me the same repository history, I tried searching for the git credentials, which I couldn't find on settings.
